# Unable to install gems - tar is corrupt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
brandon$ bundle
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using log4r (1.1.9) 
Using XMLCanonicalizer (1.0.1) 
Using multi_json (1.0.3) 
Using activesupport (3.1.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.0.3) 
Using actionpack (3.1.1) 
Using mime-types (1.17.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.2) 

Gem::Package::FormatError: corrupt gem (Gem::Package::TarInvalidError: tar is corrupt, name contains null byte) in /Users/brandon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/treetop-1.4.10.gem
An error occured while installing treetop (1.4.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install treetop -v '1.4.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have removed ruby and rvm, installed rbenv and reinstalled ruby. This is with 1.9.3-rc1, but the same thing happens in 1.9.2-p290. I have tried removing /Users/brandon/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/ to no avail. I am not sure where to turn at this point.

Also, it doesn't always happen with the treetop gem. Other times it is with activemodel or other gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are having trouble with the connection (assuming you are behind a firewall).
Try to use other internet connection (like mobile broadband).

Comment: I ended up having to switch my DNS provider from opendns to google dns.  That seemed to fix it.  Very strange.